# the meaning of function lookupTransform

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- \param target_frame The frame to which data should be transformed
- \param source_frame The frame where the data originated
- \param time The time at which the value of the transform is desired. (0 will get the latest)
- \return The transform between the frames

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped
lookupTransform(const std::string& target_frame, const std::string& source_frame,
const ros::Time& time) const;

I don't know it returns the transform from target_frame to source_frame ,or the transform from source_frame to target_frame .This makes me a little confused.
I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388113/the-meaning-of-function-lookuptransform/) by [Laura](https://answers.ros.org/users/86601/laura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The argument names for this function assume a very specific use case.

If I rename the arguments `lookupTransform(a, b, time)` then what this function does is return an object specifying the pose of frame_b relative to frame_a. For a simple planar 2D example, if frame_a and frame_b are initially aligned and have yaw=0, shifting frame_b to the right 1 meter will result in this function returning `transform.translation.x` = 1.0.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laura](https://answers.ros.org/users/86601/laura/) on 2021-10-07**:
Thank you very much for your answer!
As a beginner, I am not very familiar with some common terms in ROS.But I found through a little experiment that`lookupTransform(T2,T1,time)`(T1 and T2 are two coordinate systems)will return `transform.translation.x` which is the coordinates of the origin of T1 coordinate system in the T2 coordinate system. And I think this is the same as what you explained.
So I guess, suppose the coordinate of an object in the T2 coordinate system is X2, and the coordinate in the T1 coordinate system is X1, then X2=R21*X1+τ21, R and τ are the rotation transformation and translation transformation returned by the function , and 21 means transform from 1 to 2, which corresponds exactly to 1 as source and 2 as target.
In the sense of matrix theory, this may be a transformation matrix between the coordinate values of the same object in two different coordinate systems.But at first I thought it was a transition matrix between two coordinate systems.
Thank you again!